Topic Challenge: Let's ask about OP_CAT?
OP_CAT has been a hot topic in the Bitcoin community for a couple years, so I just looked over previous mentions to label relevant topics with a new tag.
Please use bip347-op-cat to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about the BIP proposing reintroduction of OP_CAT, how OP_CAT works, use cases for the OP_CAT opcode, and what is possible to build or not build with OP_CAT.
Please also check out the previous work, add more answers where they are missing, improve content where it should be, and vote on what's there!
This topic challenge runs until 2024-08-08. Happy posting!

There were four questions asked about OP_CAT during the challenge with a total of four answers:

Is it possible to build an Automated Market Maker with OP_CAT? – Murch [+1]
What is the OP_CAT proposal? – Murch [+1]
How can OP_CAT be used to implement additional covenants? – Brandon - Rearden [+3]
What does OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG refer to? – Murch [+3]

Thanks for posting!
